# How to solve $[x+1]=0$ for $x\in (0,1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $[x]$ be the integer part of the real $x$.

How can we solve the algebraic equation $[x+1]=0$ for $x\in (0,1)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

As $[x]=a\iff a\le x<a+1$ where $a$ is any integer

$[x+1]=0\implies 0\le x+1<1 \implies -1\le x<0$